# MySQL query being performed when PHP if condition not met?

Tags: php, mysql

The script I'm using is

```
if($profile['username'] == $user['username']) {
    $db->query("UPDATE users SET newcomments = 0 WHERE username = '$user[username]'");
    echo "This is a test";
}
```

(Note that $db->query is exactly the same as mysql_query)

For some very odd reason, the MySQL query is being performed even if the defined condition is false

The "This is a test" works properly and only appears when the condition is met, but the MySQL query is performed anyway

Whats the problem with it?

Comment: I don't see any, look more into. You might have some other query involved.

Comment: Could you post the entire script that this piece belongs to? There seems to be another problem, the query cannot be executed if the echo isn't done.

Comment: $db->query("UPDATE users SET newcomments = 0 WHERE username = '$user[username]'"); --- this should be ...WHERE username = '{$user['username']}'"); otherwise a notice is generated

Answer (score 0):

Typically the answer to such questions is somewhere else. Maybe similar SQL code is called elsewhere?

Comment: But I tried removing that script, and then the query wasn't performed

Comment: Do you know that the SQL statement executes successfully?

Comment: Yeah, as well as temporarily adding "or die(mysql_error())" I also tested the code in PHPMyAdmin and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.
Try:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($profile);
print_r($user);
```

and see if it is what you expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble believing this, either way try something like this.

```
$query="";
if($profile['username'] == $user['username']) {
    $query ="UPDATE users SET newcomments = 0 WHERE username = '" . $user[username] . "' "; 
    echo "This is a test";
}

echo $query;
$db->query($query);
```